# Javascript calculations in Cakephp

Tags: javascript, cakephp

Recently converted a perl application to cakephp 2.3. And now i'm stuck on a page which used javascript to perform some calculations. I took the javascript out and put it in a separate file, but i've also tried it directly in the view.

There are 6 tables each with 5 fields and a calculate button.The fields(milkconc and matdose) in the first column of each table are user entered. Once the user clicks out, it's supposed to perform the calculations and display them in the second column fields. When calculate is clicked, it will display the results in the 5th field. [image]

When I tab out of the first column fields, my javascript console says: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'milkconc' of undefined ' and clicking the calculate button gives a similar error for the related fields. I'm sure there is something in the javascript I need to change to fit with cakephp's forminput. I just don't know what. In my default.ctp I have `echo $this->Html->script('tid');` for the file which has all the functions.

What I thought would happen is the javascript would put the values in the appropriate fields and once save is clicked cakephp would take the value javascript put in there and put it into the database.

Edit View:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Html->css('style');
    echo $this->Html->script('tabs');
    echo $this->Html->script('tid');
?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Drug'); ?>
<i><b>These fields are currently under construction.</b></i>
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
      <td><b>Adult Dose: </b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('adultdose', array(
              'type' => 'text',
              'name' => 'adultdose',
              'size' => '24',
              'maxlength' => '250',
              'label'=> false, 
              //'class'=>'entryField'
        ));
      ?> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>RID Calculations:
      <script type="text/javascript">
         //Previously tried the javascript here.
    </script>
  </b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <table class="border">
                <tr>
                  <td class="title">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="title" align="center" nowrap><b>Dose</b></td>
                  <td class="title" align="center" nowrap><b>mg/kg/day</b></td>
                  <td class="title">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="title" align="center" nowrap><b>RID</b></td>
                  <td class="title">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td nowrap>Milk Dose (ug/L)</td>
                  <td align="center">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('milkconc', array(
                                    'type' => 'text',
                                    'name' => 'milkconc',
                                    'label' => false,
                                    'size' => '7',
                                    'maxlength' => '125',
                                    'onblur' => 'milk_amount_calc(9);'
                            ));
                    ?>
                  </td>
                  <td align="center">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('theor_infa', array(
                                    'type' => 'text',
                                    'name' => 'theor_infa',
                                    'label' => false,
                                    'size' => '7',
                                    'maxlength' => '125',
                                    //'onblur' => 'milk_amount_calc(\'9\');'
                            ));
                    ?>
                  </td>
                  <td nowrap>mg/kg/day</td>
                  <td align="center">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('rid', array(
                                    'type' => 'text',
                                    'name' => 'rid',
                                    'label' => false,
                                    'size' => '7',
                                    'maxlength' => '250',
                                    //'onblur' => 'milk_amount_calc(\'9\');'
                            ));
                    ?>
                  </td>
                  <td><button name="buttonName" value="" type="button" onclick="calculate_rid('9');">Calculate</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Mother's Dose (mg)</td>
                  <td align="center">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('matdose', array(
                                    'type' => 'text',
                                    'name' => 'matdose',
                                    'label' => false,
                                    'size' => '7',
                                    'maxlength' => '250',
                                    //'onblur' => 'mom_amount_calc(\'9\');'
                            ));
                    ?>
                  </td>
                  <td align="center">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('mdkg', array(
                                    'type' => 'text',
                                    'name' => 'mdkg',
                                    'label' => false,
                                    'size' => '7',
                                    'maxlength' => '250',
                                    //'onblur' => 'milk_amount_calc(\'9\');'
                            ));
                    ?>
                  </td>
                  <td>mg/kg/day</td>
                  <td>Reference...</td>
                  <td><!-- --></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
/* Code removed to save size. Basically the code above times 5 and each next field is fieldname1,2,3, etc */
              </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <td class="actionTable"><?php echo $this->Form->submit('Save/Update & Previous', array('name'=>'Previous')); ?></td>
  <td class="actionTable"><?php echo $this->Form->submit('Save',array('style'=>'width:150px;')); ?></td>
  <td class="actionTable"><?php echo $this->Form->submit('Save/Update & Next', array('name'=>'Next')); ?>
  <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Javascript:

```
      function milk_amount_calc(set) {
        if (set == 1) {
          var tmp = (document.form.milkconc1.value / 1000) *.15;
          var val = roundNumber(tmp, 4);
          document.form.theor_infa1.value = val;
        }
        else if (set == 2) {
          var tmp = (document.form.milkconc2.value / 1000) *.15;
          var val = roundNumber(tmp, 4);
          document.form.theor_infa2.value = val;
        }
        else if (set == 3) {
          var tmp = (document.form.milkconc3.value / 1000) *.15;
          var val = roundNumber(tmp, 4);
          document.form.theor_infa3.value = val;
        }
        else if (set == 4) {
          var tmp = (document.form.milkconc4.value / 1000) *.15;
          var val = roundNumber(tmp, 4);
          document.form.theor_infa4.value = val;
        }
        else if (set == 5) {
          var tmp = (document.form.milkconc5.value / 1000) *.15;
          var val = roundNumber(tmp, 4);
          document.form.theor_infa5.value = val;
        }
        else if (set == 9) {
          var tmp = (document.form.milkconc.value / 1000) *.15;
          var val = roundNumber(tmp, 4);
          document.form.theor_infa.value = val;
        }
      }

      function mom_amount_calc(set) {
        if (set == 1) {
          var tmp = document.form.matdose1.value /70;
          var val = roundNumber(tmp, 4);
          document.form.mdkg1.value = val;
        }
        else if (set == 2) {
          var tmp = document.form.matdose2.value /70;
          var val = roundNumber(tmp, 4);
          document.form.mdkg2.value = val;
        }
        else if (set == 3) {
          var tmp = document.form.matdose3.value /70;
          var val = roundNumber(tmp, 4);
          document.form.mdkg3.value = val;
        }
        else if (set == 4) {
          var tmp = document.form.matdose4.value /70;
          var val = roundNumber(tmp, 4);
          document.form.mdkg4.value = val;
        }
        else if (set == 5) {
          var tmp = document.form.matdose5.value /70;
          var val = roundNumber(tmp, 4);
          document.form.mdkg5.value = val;
        }
        else if (set == 9) {
          var tmp = document.form.matdose.value /70;
          var val = roundNumber(tmp, 4);
          document.form.mdkg.value = val;
        }
      }

      var set_0 = 0;
      var set_1 = 0;
      var set_2 = 0;
      var set_3 = 0;
      var set_4 = 0;
      var set_5 = 0;

      var low = 0;
      var high = 0;

      function calculate_rid(set) {
        if (set == 1) {
          if (document.form.theor_infa1.value == 0 || document.form.mdkg1.value == 0) {
            alert("Milk Dose and Mother's Dose are Required\nCan't Calculate the Relative Infant Dose(RID)");
            return;
          }
          set_1 = (document.form.theor_infa1.value / document.form.mdkg1.value) * 100;
          set_1 = roundNumber(set_1, 4);
          var val = set_1 + '%';
          document.form.rid1.value = val;
        }
        else if (set == 2) {
          if (document.form.theor_infa2.value == 0 || document.form.mdkg2.value == 0) {
            alert("Milk Dose and Mother's Dose are Required\nCan't Calculate the Relative Infant Dose(RID)");
            return;
          }
          set_2 = (document.form.theor_infa2.value / document.form.mdkg2.value) * 100;
          set_2 = roundNumber(set_2, 4);
          var val = set_2 + '%';
          document.form.rid2.value = val;
        }
        else if (set == 3) {
          if (document.form.theor_infa3.value == 0 || document.form.mdkg3.value == 0) {
            alert("Milk Dose and Mother's Dose are Required\nCan't Calculate the Relative Infant Dose(RID)");
            return;
          }
          set_3 = (document.form.theor_infa3.value / document.form.mdkg3.value) * 100;
          set_3 = roundNumber(set_3, 4);
          var val = set_3 + '%';
          document.form.rid3.value = val;
        }
        else if (set == 4) {
          if (document.form.theor_infa4.value == 0 || document.form.mdkg4.value == 0) {
            alert("Milk Dose and Mother's Dose are Required\nCan't Calculate the Relative Infant Dose(RID)");
            return;
          }
          set_4 = (document.form.theor_infa4.value / document.form.mdkg4.value) * 100;
          set_4 = roundNumber(set_4, 4);
          var val = set_4 + '%';
          document.form.rid4.value = val;
        }
        else if (set == 5) {
          if (document.form.theor_infa5.value == 0 || document.form.mdkg5.value == 0) {
            alert("Milk Dose and Mother's Dose are Required\nCan't Calculate the Relative Infant Dose(RID)");
            return;
          }
          set_5 = (document.form.theor_infa5.value / document.form.mdkg5.value) * 100;
          set_5 = roundNumber(set_5, 4);
          var val = set_5 + '%';
          document.form.rid5.value = val;
        }
        else if (set == 9) {
          if (document.form.theor_infa.value == 0 || document.form.mdkg.value == 0) {
            alert("Milk Dose and Mother's Dose are Required\nCan't Calculate the Relative Infant Dose(RID)");
            return;
          }
          set_0 = (document.form.theor_infa.value / document.form.mdkg.value) * 100;
          set_0 = roundNumber(set_0, 4);
          var val = set_0 + '%';
          document.form.rid.value = val;
        } 
        set_rid_range();
      }

      function set_rid_range() {
        var arr = new Array();
        var rng = new Array();

        arr[0] = replacer(document.form.rid.value); 
        arr[1] = replacer(document.form.rid1.value); 
        arr[2] = replacer(document.form.rid2.value); 
        arr[3] = replacer(document.form.rid3.value); 
        arr[4] = replacer(document.form.rid4.value); 
        arr[5] = replacer(document.form.rid5.value); 

        arr = arr.sort(sortNumber);

        var this_total = 0;
        for(a = 0; a < arr.length; a++) {
          this_total = this_total + parseFloat(arr[a]); 
          if (arr[a] > 0) {
            rng.push(arr[a]);
          }
        }
        if (this_total == 0) {
          document.form.rid_range.value =  '';  
          return;
        }
        rng = rng.sort(sortNumber);

        var low = rng[0];
        var high = rng.pop();

        if ((low == high) && (low == 0)) {
          document.form.rid_range.value =  '';     
          return;
        }

        if (low == high) {
          document.form.rid_range.value =  high + '%';
        }
        else {
          document.form.rid_range.value = low + '% - ' + high + '%';
        }
      }

      function sortNumber(a,b) {
        return a - b;
      }

      function replacer(d) {
        return d.replace('%','');
      }

      function roundNumber(rnum, rlength) {
        // Arguments: number to round, number of decimal places
        var newnumber = Math.round(rnum*Math.pow(10,rlength))/Math.pow(10,rlength);
        return newnumber;
      }
```

Comment: There is some other javascript in other files, is it possible i'm missing some?

Comment: I will be trying to get the element by ID since I know cake gives an id for each form input in the format of ModelFieldName. Going to try var sometmp = document.getElementById('myText'); and then access the value by doing sometmp.value but I don't know how I would put that into the field it's supposed to be put in.

Comment: Well I got the javascript working properly, but CakePHP isn't saving the fields I put the calculations in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After double checking that I have the script available through the normal cake setup(declaring the script in default.ctp via `echo $this->Html->script('tid');`) and double checking the error given in the javascript console, I narrowed the issue down to the javascript. As it turns out, it was attempting to access the values incorrectly from the cakephp generated form.

To correct the problem I just had to change in the javascript `document.form.fieldname.value` to `document.getElementById('ModelFieldName').value` so it accessed the correct form elements based on the cake created ID's.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute all your javascript code when the document is loaded:

```
window.onload = function() {
    // your js code here
};
```

Explanation: The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM. So if your script executes before the document is parsed, when you try to read some property you will get an error.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand. Where would I put the window.onload? I didn't think my script did anything until the user either clicked the button or tabbed out of the first column fields. It looked like the javascript was running just fine, but I didn't change it from the old form so it's not accessing the form correctly to get the values?

Comment: What I attempted from my comments above appears to work. It displayed an alert properly at least, will test further. In the javascript I changed 'document.form.fieldname.value' to 'document.getElementById('fieldid').value'. I don't know if this is the best way to access it though.